# Calling Dynamically Created Control From Code Behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, innerhtml

I am creating a control dynamically using the `HtmlGenericControl` method, and then trying to call that control a few lines down in my code. Obviously, because this control is not actually created yet, the code throws build errors. Is there anyway to work around this? This is the code that I am working with:

```
foreach(string t in equipmentTypes)
{
    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");//Create html control <li>
    //Create the correct <li> for the equipment type. Using the naming convention tableAbreviation_recordName eg: et_ATV.
    li.InnerHtml = "<div id='et_" + t +"' >" + t + "<label><input type='checkbox'></label></div><ul id='make' runat='server'>";
    equipmentType.Controls.Add(li);
}

makes = Statements.GetMake();

foreach(string t in makes)
{
    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");//Create html control <li>
    //Create the correct <li> for the equipment type. Using the naming convention tableAbreviation_recordName eg: et_ATV.
    li.InnerHtml = "<div id='mk_" + t + "' >" + t + "<label><input type='checkbox'></label></div>";
    make.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

So I am creating the `<ul>` with id='make'. I want to call this `<ul>` in the next foreach loop an append some html to it. How would I go about this?

After some additional research, I tried the `Page.FindControl` to find the control, but in the order the code runs/page is created, the object is not set to an instance of an object. So it looks like I may need to call the control after the page has rendered?

The code that I used to try and find the control is the same as the previous foreach loop, except the last line.

```
foreach(string t in makes)
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");//Create html control <li>
                    //Create the correct <li> for the equipment type. Using the naming convention tableAbreviation_recordName eg: et_ATV.
                    li.InnerHtml = "<div id='mk_" + t + "' >" + t + "<label><input type='checkbox'></label></div>";
                    Page.FindControl("ATV_make").Controls.Add(li);
                }
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are attempting to find this control?

Comment: updated. I actually moved on to trying to utilize the ASP:Repeater control. I still do not have it working though.

Comment: where are you creating a control with the ID 'ATV_make'?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not explain that part correctly. The value from the database that is being retireved would be ATV.

but I have figured out a workaround using the repeater. Thank you for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I was able to find an ASP.NET control called the Repeater. This works great when creating dynamic ul's.

This is the code that I used to dynamically load the values from my database.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate><li><div id="et_"><%# Eval("EquipmentTypeName") %><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div><ul id="_make" runat="server">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL_Make">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><div id="mk_"><%# Eval("MakeName") %><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div><ul id="_year" runat="server"></ul></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul></li></ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```